# Relation to the same type of entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have this entity class:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? OwnerAccoutId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Account OwnerAccout { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Account> ChildsAccouts{ get; set; }
}
```

An account can have 0 or 1 owner and many childs. I don't know how construct the relationship with fluent-api. I tried many ways without success.

Someone can i help me? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Map

```
public AccoutMap()
{
    ToTable("Accounts");

    Property(c => c.Code).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
    Property(c => c.Description).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);

    HasOptional(c => c.OwnerAccount).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.OwnerAccoutId);
    HasOptional(c => c.ChildsAccout).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.OwnerAccoutId);
}
```

I get this error:

> InvalidCastException: Can not convert an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Account_4946F7B05C862EE76E8535A251C267196936C8F963C26EBC2FABDAADDE4715B4' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1 [Base.Entities.Account]

I understand that because I'm setting the model wrong, the entity framework interprets ChildsAccouts as Accout type instead of ICollection . I'm just starting with CodeFirst.

**EDIT 2:**

I tried:

```
HasOptional(c => c.OwnerAccount).WithMany(c => c.ChildsAccounts).HasForeignKey(c => c.OwnerAccoutId);
```

Error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details.'
>
> Inner Exception InvalidOperationException: An open DataReader is
>   already associated with this Command, you must close it first.

**EDIT 3**

The last relationship work correctly. Fix the error adding "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" to my connection string.

Comment: Can you show current version of mapping which you have and describe what is wrong with that mapping?

Comment: Yes, i added it.

Comment: Your Edit2 mapping seems fine. Can you also post the query that you're executing when you get this error? This usually happens when you are iterating through the results of a query and you issue another one while iterating and you don't have Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) enabled.

Comment: Thanks Akos Nagy, I added MARS to my connection string and all works fine. It's a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this relationship and work fine:

```
HasOptional(c => c.OwnerAccount).WithMany(c => c.ChildsAccounts).HasForeignKey(c => c.OwnerAccoutId);
```